# Saving file name of cell content

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use vba to save a file with name based on the content of a cell.

I have found the following resource which has been helpful.

https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-save-file-based-on-cell-value-in-excel.html

But the content of the cell that im trying to put in the file name is a date of format dd/mm/yyyy, is it possible to change the format in the file name to be yyyy-mm-dd, and how would i go about doing this

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say it's a defined range called `myCell`; Just replace `myCell.Value` in your code with `Format(myCell.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")`.

Comment: I did think of changing the cell value before using it, but it didn't sound in the question like you wanted the value changed? However just changing the number format as @dzardo suggested is totally viable.

Answer (score 1):

one simple solution would be to change the number formart of that cell before retrieving it to the name. For that you could use the code line below:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Comment: If you did this you'd have to use `cell.text` as `cell.value` wouldn't change - credit to @Error1004 for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I my opinion what you need is to create a string in order to be used as a name by re structuring the date and not by changing the format of the date. You could use:

`=YEAR(A1) & "-" &RIGHT("0" & MONTH(A1),2) & "-" & RIGHT("0" & DAY(A1),2)`

[image]

Comment: Why not the format? Totally agree that this solution works, but isn't just using a formatted value simpler?

Comment: it trying to use the value of the cell as a name. By changing the format you keep the value as it is.

Comment: Get it - changing the format in the cell won't work if using `cell.value`. However if you used `cell.text` ...